# Windows Phone Memory Profilers

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm currently having a hard time driving down the peak memory consumption of my background agent below the 6MB limit. Are there any recommendations for WP7 capable memory profilers. I am not even asking for something along the lines of dotTrace but basically anything that offers some insight about what's going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Windows Phone SDK comes with a profiler for both memory consumption, and other things, that's available in Visual Studio after installation of the SDK.

You can [read more about it on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202934%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

Also, try look isolated at the background agent code, and move it to a separate application, where you run it in the foreground. That could possible make it easier for you to nail where the problem is.