# WP8 Out of Memory error while loading Images

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, out-of-memory, coverflow

I am working on Windows Phone 8 app.

I am working on Coverflow feature, i am trying to load 600 items but it always shows `Out of Memory Error`

Code:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate1">
            <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Border Grid.Row="0" Height="400" Width="400" CornerRadius="30,30,30,30">
                    <Border.Background>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/sample.png" />
                    </Border.Background>
                </Border>
                <Grid Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               Margin="5,20,5,5"
                               Foreground="#000000"
                               Text="{Binding Title}"/>
                </Grid>
                <Grid Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               Margin="5,5,5,20"
                               Foreground="#000000"
                               Text="{Binding SubTitle}"/>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
```

I have tried checking why its happening so,because each time it loads image with the below code

```
<Border Grid.Row="0" Height="400" Width="400" CornerRadius="30,30,30,30">
                        <Border.Background>
                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/sample.png" />
                        </Border.Background>
                    </Border>
```

I tried removing `Width` and `Height` and it works but i want the image to bigger.

How can i fix this ?

Comment: why do you have a wpf tag? You got 300MB limit on windows phone 8, if you do the math you will find that this is not enough for 600 pictures of that size

Comment: I don't know if WPF uses the same image instance for all of your 600 items or not. Have you tried putting the `ImageBrush` in a resource and then referencing it using `StaticResource`?

Comment: @Dirk it's not a wpf question

Comment: Guys i have removed the wpf tag please upvote

Comment: @Dirk i am binding the data dynamically, so i did not get your point

Comment: @thumbmunkeys Doesn't really matter whether it's WPF or WP8. The principle should still be the same.

Comment: @Dirk yes thats what i was also pointing to

Comment: @Dirk is there any way that i can avoid this  or something like load all the items and then display ?

Comment: Is it a ListBox? You should virtualize. There are a lot of questions here at SO about that.

Comment: @MikaelDúiBolinder its very similar to list box

Comment: E.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13816569/why-do-i-get-an-outofmemoryexception-when-i-have-images-in-my-listbox

Comment: @MikaelDúiBolinder how can i bind the data to my `Border Imagebrush`

Comment: I think this realy a bad approach for loading 600 images at a time when your image size is 400x400(considering at most 2 images per in phone area) you need to implement some virtulization. only load images which are currently visible and 4 images before and after the visiable images. and dispose previously shown images form memory

Comment: @MuhammadSaifullah can you help on that ?

Answer (score 1):

Here it's been discussed in detail. What you'll need to do is use Memory Profiling and periodically check which the memory Heap to see what's allocated when it shouldn't be.

[How to debug running out of memory on Windows Phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14781547/how-to-debug-running-out-of-memory-on-windows-phone)